# How to remove locate control and then again add it on map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Below is my code to get current location on map
but before adding this i want to remove / reset map if control is already available on map.

```
    this.map = L.mapbox.map('map', null, {}).
        addControl(L.control.scale()).
        setView(DEFAULT_LAT_LONG, DEFAULT_ZOOM);
    L.control.locate({
        locateOptions: {
           maxZoom: 15
        }
    }).addTo(this.map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.removeFrom(map)` the same way you use `.addTo(map)`, but first you should assign your control to a variable:

```
var myCtrl = L.control.locate({
    locateOptions: {
       maxZoom: 15
    }
  }).addTo(this.map);

myCtrl.removeFrom(map); // remove it

myCtrl.addTo(map); // add it again
```